# Labels should not cover features

Tags: qgis, labeling, features

How do I tell QGIS that my labels should not cover features in layer 1 and layer 2, while it is OK to cover layers 3 and 4?

qgis version 2.18.7

Comment: Are all four of your layers showing labels?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].